# How to disable Fast Boot on Asus zenbook for EFI boot

Tags: installation, grub2, uefi, asus

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 on my Asus ux52a Zenbook. I get the following error message:

**GRUB Installation failed**
*The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.*

I've been trying to follow the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI, but I can't figure out how to disable FastBoot and Intel SRT. I can enter setup during POST, but I don't see these options anywhere. Anyone know where to find them?

Answer (score 1):

The option that's critical to disable is *not* the "fast boot" feature in the firmware; it's the "fast startup" feature in Windows. This feature turns shutdown operations into suspend-to-disk operations, which means that the filesystems are left in an inconsistent state, which is a recipe for disaster when you dual-boot. See [this Windows forum page](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) for details on how to disable this feature.

I know less about the Intel SRT feature, so I can't really comment on it.