# How may I reduce my startup time of 27.766s please?

Tags: boot, kernel

Below is the output for my Zenbook from systemd-analyze plot > sequence.svg

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS mike-UX305FA (Linux 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017) x86-64
Startup finished in 8.281s (firmware) + 1.908s (loader) + 11.613s (kernel) + 5.963s (userspace) = 27.766s
```

My Zenbook has

```
Intel® Core™ m3-6Y30 Processor
RAM: 8 GB
Storage: 128 GB SSDIntel® Core™ m3-6Y30 Processor
RAM: 8 GB
Storage: 128 GB SSD
```

I checked the output for my rarely used msi laptop which was

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS mike-Capella-platform (Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016) x84-64
Startup finished in 3.788s (kernel) + 3.068s (userspace) = 6.856s
```

The msi has

```
Intel® Core™ is CPU M350@2.27GHzx4 Processor
RAM: 1.88 GB
Storage: 256 GB SSD
```

What catches my eye about the differences are:

```
Zenbook: Startup finished in **8.281s (firmware)** + **1.908s (loader)** + **11.613s (kernel)** + 5.963s (userspace) = **27.766s**
```

against

**no firmware and loader and short kernel** here for the

msi: Startup finished in 3.788s (kernel) + 3.068s (userspace) = **6.856s**

Comment: What does `systemd-analyze blame` tell you?

Comment: http://hantsnwa.org.uk/systemd-analyze%20blame

Comment: Perhaps this similar question will help? http://askubuntu.com/a/615429/305014

Comment: Not sure if the following is relevant.

Comment: Not sure if the following is relevant. My dual boot msi boots using BIOS and W10 takes some 30 seconds to boot there. This my Zenbook is also dual boot and boots using UEFI firmware taking some 30 seconds to boot W10.  Maybe UEFI accounts for the extra 8.281s (firmware),  1.908s (loader)  and longer 11.613s (kernel) when booting Ubuntu ?

Comment: Re  user8675309    However systemd-analyze blame shows just 
          8.243s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                     (bedtime for me now. Will continue tomorrow)

Comment: Have you enabled fast boot in your bios? Also, perhaps the issue with your WIN10 boot is because windows is not actually shutting down your Zenbook, and is instead suspending to disk, as explained here: http://askubuntu.com/a/344433/305014.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55679/discussion-between-welshmike-and-user8675309).

Comment: OK I give up and am thinking of doing the following: